# Reading a full array in R, instead of reading it member by member

Tags: r

I am using `httr` to retrieve an `http` response in R:

```
my_recs = POST(url,body=readChar(fileName, file.info(fileName)$size), do.call(add_headers, hd))
my_recs_str = content(my_recs)
my_recs_data = my_recs_str$data
```

I am trying to retrieve the entire set of IDs that are stored in `my_recs_data`, buy I was only able to reach them using double brackets:

```
my_ids[i] = my_recs_data[[i]]$id
```

Is there any way to retrieve all IDs without looping one by one through them?
Thank you.

Comment: Do include the output of `dput(my_recs_data)` in your question in the future. Most people can probably infer that this is a nested list based on the context, but that's not always the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can vectorise your code as follows:

```
my_ids = sapply(my_recs_data, `[[`, 'id')
```

This is equivalent to `my_recs_data[[i]][['id']]` rather than `…$id`. However, in practice this shouldn’t make a difference.

Comment: Thanks.What should I do in a case I have a double reference - `prod_name=my_recs_data[[rec]]$productName$FullName`

Comment: I think I got it right, `sapply(my_recs_data, '[[','productName')['FullName',]`

Comment: @RoeeAnuar Careful, note that I used backticks in my code around `[[`, not single quotes. Single quotes happen to work but I’d argue that they are sloppy style and that R *shouldn’t* accept them.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Konrad!

For creating a vector from the nested list based on one attribute, 
instead of looping through:

```
my_ids[i] = my_recs_data[[i]]$id
```

I used:

```
my_ids = sapply(my_recs_data, `[[`, 'id')
```

for two nested attributes, instead of looping through:

```
prod_names[i]=my_recs_data[[i]]$productName$FullName
```

I used:

```
prod_names=sapply(my_recs_data, '[[','productName')['FullName',]
```

And instead of the most complicated one:

```
sku[i]=my_recs_data[[i]]$productSKU[[1]]$value
```

I used double sapply:

```
sku=sapply(sapply(my_recs_data,'[[','productSKU') ,'[[','value')
```